# Listen to address with webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, gruntjs, webpack-dev-server, browser-sync

With `browser-sync` in Grunt you do this to listen on some URL:

```
"options": {
    "watchTask": true,
    "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
    "injectChanges": true,
}
```

How can you do the same thing with `webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: By listening, you want webpack-dev-server to serve content on that url:port?

Comment: No, I want to take content from that url:port.

Comment: That is not possible though. You can pass host and port, so webpack-dev-server is going to spin a server where your bundle is going to be available there.